# Start javascript after lazy load images

Tags: javascript, function, load, element, lazy-evaluation

I have a problem with a javascript. The script causes three elements on my website to be the same size. I would like to load my pictures by lazy load. This makes the rendering incorrect because the size of the elements is calculated by the script without the images. Is it possible to give the javascript a function that it will start only after the images have been loaded successfully by lazy load?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
function kb_equal_height() {
  var highest_element = 0;

  // Delete the height
  $('.navigation-left,.site-content,.widget-area').each(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('style');
  });

  // Check which element is highest
  $('.navigation-left,.site-content,.widget-area').each(function() {
    if ($(this).height() > highest_element) {
      highest_element = $(this).height();
    }
  });

  // Assign this height to all elements
  $('.navigation-left,.site-content,.widget-area').each(function() {
    $(this).height(highest_element);
  });
};

window.onload = kb_equal_height;

var resizeTimer;
$(window).resize(function() {
  clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
  resizeTimer = setTimeout(kb_equal_height, 100);
});

});
</script>
```

Comment: You can try to load images asynchronously and set them to `img` tags. Also, you can assign specific classes to these elements that will define the dimensions.

Comment: I think you can use [`.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) on the `img` tags to recall the function each time a image is loaded

Comment: Thank you for answer! I try to set img tags, but i don´t get it.

Comment: Can you give me a sample for a .onload script on img tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`image.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/image.onload) to call the function when the image finished to load

You might not really see it in action here as the images probably won't take long enough to load for you to see intermediate state but it works

you'll need to clean your cache if you want to see it in action a second time as your browser will load the images from cache the second, third... times

```js
let nbCat = 0
let div = document.getElementById("nbImg")

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("doAction")).forEach(img => {
  img.onload = imgLoaded // your function here
})

function imgLoaded(e) {
  nbCat++
  div.textContent = nbCat + " cat" + (nbCat > 1? "s":"") + " loaded"
}
```

```css
img {
  max-height: 50vh
}
```

```html
<img class="doAction" src="https://r.hswstatic.com/w_907/gif/tesla-cat.jpg">
<img class="doAction" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Cat03.jpg/1200px-Cat03.jpg">
<img class="doAction" src="https://pre00.deviantart.net/5d96/th/pre/f/2012/103/d/d/dd0d35acf8ea1817dffe7677f018b5a4-d4vzsbg.jpg">
<img class="doAction" src="https://pre00.deviantart.net/758d/th/pre/f/2018/006/2/7/tigerfieldadjusted_by_mssylviarose-dbz65qt.jpg">
<div id="nbImg">no cat loaded</div>
```